# I am trying to fill a graph, what is the most optimized way to store the explored nodes?

Tags: java, optimization, graph, nodes

I'm using an ArrayList and then using contains to see if the new node is already explored. Is there a better way? Time and space wise?

Comment: Use a structure that has better then O(N) contains: HashSet

Answer (score 1):

HashSet, alternatively if you are worried about duplicate keys a HashMap where the key is the Nodes HAshValue and the Value is the node

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a boolean [][][][] explored. It was much faster.